# Cambiar tamaño de una grilla con bootstrap

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap

tengo el siguiente problema tengo una tabla y quiero modificar el tamaño ya que no me entra en la pagina como puedo hacer?
Dejo el mi código

```
<body>


<form runat="server">

<br />
<br />

<h3 align="center">FILTRAR TRANSACCIONES DE DETERMINADAS CUENTAS</h3>

<br />
<br />


    <table class="table table-hover table-dark" >
        <tr>
            <td>
                 <asp:GridView ID="grDatos" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Transaccion Id" DataField="TransaccionId" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Codigo Cuenta" DataField="CodigoCuenta" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Descripcion Cuenta" DataField="CuentaDescripcion" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID Secundaria" DataField="ID_Secundaria" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID CTA Secundaria" DataField="ID_CTA_Secundaria" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Nombre Secundaria" DataField="Nombre_Secundaria" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Fechas de creacion" DataField="Fecha_Creacion" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Tipos de comprobante" DataField="TipoComprobante" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Codigo de comprobante" DataField="CodigoComprobante" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Descripcion Jornal" DataField="JornalDescripcion" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Monto Neto" DataField="MontoNeto" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Fecha de registro" DataField="Fecha_Efectiva" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Linea Descripcion" DataField="LineaDescripcion" />                                                     
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Usuario" DataField="nombreApellido_usuario" />                        
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Movimiento" DataField="Descripcion" />                        
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Fecha de carga al sistema" DataField="FechaCargaSistema" />                      
                </Columns>
             <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
             <EmptyDataTemplate >
            <asp:Label ID="lblNoTieneDato" runat="server"  
                Text="LA CONSULTA NO TRAE DATOS" ForeColor="Yellow" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>                    
                <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:GridView>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>



    <br />
    <br />

   <asp:Label ID="lblDescargar" runat="server" Text="Descargue todas las transacciones: "></asp:Label>
   <asp:Button ID="btnExcel" runat="server" Text="Descargar a Excel" OnClick="btnExcel_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" />

<br />

<asp:Label ID="lblMensaje" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>



</form>

  <!-- Jquery JS-->
<script src="../vendor/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS-->
<script src="../vendor/bootstrap-4.1/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/bootstrap-4.1/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Vendor JS       -->
<script src="../vendor/slick/slick.min.js">
</script>
<script src="../vendor/wow/wow.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/animsition/animsition.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js">
</script>
<script src="../vendor/counter-up/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/counter-up/jquery.counterup.min.js">
</script>
<script src="../vendor/circle-progress/circle-progress.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/chartjs/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendor/select2/select2.min.js">
</script>

<!-- Main JS-->
<script src="../js/main.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, si tienes bootstrap configurado en tu web, solo debes poner el siguiente codigo en el tag `<body>`

`<body class="container">` o `<body class="container-fluid">`

ambos tienes maneras distintas (por temas de margen) de contener el cuerpo de una web.

No dudes en preguntar.

**EDIT**

Aclaro que esto soluciona tu problema de contener la tabla dentro de la página, existe otro método menos "delicado" que es poner la tabla y formulario dentro de un `<div>` y asignar tamaños pero en estos tiempos de "bootstrap" es mal visto.

Echa un vistazo a la siguiente página para mas información.

[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: puse el container y el container-fluid en el body pero nada, tmb probe con el div y poner table responsive pero es lo mismo tmb, lo que yo qiuiero es que se vea todo el contenido de la tabla en la pantalla.. osea todas las columnas en la pantalla... o como hago para que el formato de la tabla sea un poco mas chico? igual gracias

Comment: Estimado, al parecer dentro de GridView existen las propiedades Height y Width, con aquellos puedes setear un tamaño a tu gusto, prueba y me avisas
**EDIT** setea como el ejemplo   `<asp:GridView heigth="450" width="450">`

Comment: se puede! entra todo el contenido de la tabla en la pantalla, pero sacando la librerias de bootstrap. Una vez que se coloca la libreria de nuevo con el estilo vuelve de nuevo al tamaño de la foto

Comment: podrías editar tu pregunta con todo el codigo de front end?? así te podría ayudar de mejor manera, creo que te faltan contenedores para que funcione.

Comment: ya edite la publicacion! Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Ya estimado, agrega en el body lo mismo que dije en el comentario anterior y cambia todos esos scripts a la parte superior, dentro del tag `<head> *** </head>`, creo que el problema de visualización es que bootstrap no está cargando al momento de traer la información, por lo que intenta dibujar con la información ya puesta en el navegador, me comentas como te va.

Comment: @harifo no es buena idea ni buena práctica mandar todos los scripts dentro del `<head>` de la página. A menos que estés utilizando `async` o `defer`, no deberías recomendarlo como solución.

Answer (score 0):

Hola si no quieres cambiar el estilo de la tabla que te ofrece bootstrap puedes escalarla con *transform* al tamaño que te vaya bien, en tu caso seria:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-dark" style="transform: scale(0.8);">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:GridView ID="grDatos" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Transaccion Id" DataField="TransaccionId" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Codigo Cuenta" DataField="CodigoCuenta" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Descripcion Cuenta" DataField="CuentaDescripcion" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID Secundaria" DataField="ID_Secundaria" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID CTA Secundaria" DataField="ID_CTA_Secundaria" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Nombre Secundaria" DataField="Nombre_Secundaria" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Fechas de creacion" DataField="Fecha_Creacion" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Tipos de comprobante" DataField="TipoComprobante" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Codigo de comprobante" DataField="CodigoComprobante" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Descripcion Jornal" DataField="JornalDescripcion" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Monto Neto" DataField="MontoNeto" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Fecha de registro" DataField="Fecha_Efectiva" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Linea Descripcion" DataField="LineaDescripcion" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Usuario" DataField="nombreApellido_usuario" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Movimiento" DataField="Descripcion" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Fecha de carga al sistema" DataField="FechaCargaSistema" />
                    </Columns>
                    <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblNoTieneDato" runat="server" Text="LA CONSULTA NO TRAE DATOS"
                            ForeColor="Yellow" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```